# Problem using cloud masking

Tags: arcgis-desktop, landsat

I am using Landsat 8 L2C2 products and I am trying to use Quality Assessment Band for Cloud Masking. The problem is that, I don't know which values to use on the remap properties tool. I am expressing bellow my procedure of cloud masking (Image 2,3), is my logic right? Can someone explain how to use QA_Pixel in order to do cloud masking?

**Image 1: Information about QA_PIXEL from USGS.**
[image]

**Image 2: In order to use QA_Pixel we need to open Remap Properties Tool and set the correct minimum and maximum values.**
[image]
**Image 3: Using Clip Properties Tool we clip the result of Remap Properties Tool in order to get the Cloud Masked Image.**
[image]
**Image 4: Bit Index**
[image]